# Clojure regex matching

Tags: regex, clojure

I'm trying to match a pattern **at a certain position k** (k=3 in the example below) in a string.

I've tried

```
(re-seq #"^alex" (str (drop 3 "xxxalexandre")))
```

but it does not match anything (`=> nil`)

What is the Clojure-way to do this ? (I'm on Clojure 1.4.0)

A good alternative would be to match the pattern anywhere, but then I would need the **position** where it found the pattern in the input. Can I do this without accessing the `java.util.regex.Matcher` instance ? (which I've been told is very bad, since it's mutable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression `(str (drop 3 ...` should be `(apply str (drop 3 ...`.

But, better would be to use `subs`:

```
user=> (re-seq #"^alex" (subs "xxxalexandre" 3))
("alex")
```

Or, if you like, go in three characters in your regular expression:

```
user=> (map second (re-seq #"^...(alex)" "xxxalexandre"))
("alex")
```

For your follow-up, finding the location of the match, one way (for simple cases) would be to use `.indexOf` on the result:

```
user=> ((fn [s p] (let [[m] (re-seq p s)] [m (.indexOf s m)])) "xxxalexandre" #"alex")
["alex" 3]
```

Comment: Thanks ! Any idea about the alternative way (see my edited question) ?

Answer (score 4):

Try see what `(str (drop 3 "xxxalexandre"))` returns:

```
=> (str (drop 3 "xxxalexandre"))
"clojure.lang.LazySeq@a65bc80b"
```

Since drop returns a lazy sequence, the arguments of str is a lazy sequence, and what's returned is the .toString of that lazy sequence, namely a string of the object reference.

```
=> (drop 3 "xxxalexandre")
(\a \l \e \x \a \n \d \r \e)

=> (str (lazy-seq `(\a \l \e \x \a \n \d \r \e)))
"clojure.lang.LazySeq@a65bc80b"
```

Use `apply` to realize the lazy seq and put the collection into the str function as multiple arguments.

```
=> (apply str (lazy-seq '(\a \l \e \x \a \n \d \r \e)))
"alexandre"

=> (apply str (drop 3 "xxxalexandre"))
"alexandre"
```

Now your regex wil match:

```
=> (re-seq #"^alex" (apply str (drop 3 "xxxalexandre")))
("alex")
```

Answer (score 2):

$ in regex maps to the end of a line.. you probably want ^alex

Comment: Oups you're right ! Edited question, it is still returning nil. thanks for the catch.